# Create array from points

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, mootools

I need to format an array from a list of values.

Currently I have the following hard-coded points:

```
points = [
{x: 20, y: 112},
{x: 23, y: 101},
{x: 51, y: 89},
{x: 63, y: 89},
{x: 84, y: 129},
{x: 64, y: 153},
{x: 45, y: 151},
{x: 38, y: 140},
{x: 28, y: 150},
{x: 10, y: 144},
{x: 0, y: 130},
{x: 10, y: 114}
];
```

The resulting array is to be passed to a function.

I now need to pass another array to the same function but I cannot hard-coded them as above. Instead, I am using a JS framework to grab the points dynamically using, for example, $(#container).get('points');

How do I convert the new array so that it is formatted similarly to the  x: | y: structure as above?

```
points="20,112, 23,101, 51,89, 63,89, 84,129, 64,153, 45,151, 38,140, 28,150, 10,144, 0,130, 10,114"
```

I found the following in MooTools:

```
Array.each([1, 2, 3], function(number, index)
{
    alert('x:' + number + ', y: ' + index);
});
```

...but somehow that doesn't seem like the correct way to do this.

Can I get a little guidance please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can [`split` *<sup>[docs]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) the string and iterate over it, taking two values in each iteration:

```
var parts = points.split(',');
var pointsArray = [];

for(var i = 0, l = parts.length; i < l; i += 2) {
    pointsArray.push({x: +parts[i], y: +parts[i+1]});
}
```

Comment: I tried it out but all it displayed was [object,object] several times. I'm assuming I need to use split twice as Laurent recommends?

Comment: @Jsus: Don't know, maybe your actual data is different. Works good with the example data you provided: http://jsfiddle.net/EUrs3/1/. Of course each element of the array *is* an object, so when you call `alert` or just convert each element to a string, it will show `[object Object]`. This is the default string representation of an object.

Comment: Excellent!! This works brilliantly. Thank you. My error came from attempting to write the array to a div using $('displayArray').set('text', pointsArray);

Comment: for that to work I'd have to use foreach() or something along those lines?

Comment: You mean printing the array? You could use `JSON.stringify` like I did, or use whatever Mootools provides. Otherwise you have to iterate over the array and access each `x` and `y` coordinate and build the the string.

Comment: Yeah. it's working backwards, I know but was curious. Thanks so much for your assistance! My code works just fine now.

Answer (score 0):

You should actualy split it twice:

```
var points = "12,12, 1,2, 3,4"
var arr = points.split(', ');
for(var i = 0; i< arr.length; i++)
{
  var point = arr[i].split(',');
  document.write(point+ ' <br />' );
  arr[i] = {x:point[0], y:point[1]};
  document.write('   '+arr[i].x + ' ' + arr[i].y + ' <br/>');
}
```

Apart from that, just like the other comment.

Comment: Ah, ok! @Laurent, How do I set the results to a variable I can pass to my main function?

pointsArray = (arr[i].x + ',' + arr[i].y);
    

like so?